# Named Range that is a Formula in Another Workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, named-ranges

I am trying to do something somewhat convoluted, so if at any point someone stops me and says "stop reinventing the wheel, this is the easy solution" I will be overjoyed.

I have ~50 "chart" workbooks that I need to update the named ranges in. These named ranges are in a "master" workbook, and each range is a cell with a formula in it (minus the "="). These formulas all refer to sheet names in the ~50 chart workbooks; each workbook is unique but the sheet names are the same throughout them.

Example formula:

`if(COUNTA(DataHistory!$A:$A)<31,offset(DataHistory!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(DataHistory!$A:$A)-1),offset(DataHistory!$A$1, COUNTA(DataHistory!$A:$A)-30,0,31))`

DataHistory is the name of a sheet in all workbooks.

To avoid copy/pasting ~30 named range formulas into ~50 workbooks, I want the Chart workbooks to refer to the named range on the master and then see that formula as a formula. So far, I have gotten the Chart workbook to see the named range in the other workbook and I've been able to concatenate the formula with an "=".

`CONCATENATE("=",[cellwithformula])`

That just gives me a text string with `=if(COUNTA(DataHistory!$A:$A)<31,offset(DataHistory!$A$` etc. etc.

I then tried:

`INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("=",[cellwithformula])`

and

`EVAL([cellwithformula])`

And none of this is working. I have a sneaky feeling that it does not like that I'm trying to make it reference a formula in a cell in another workbook that references back to a sheet in the current workbook.

Like I said, convoluted. Please let me know if I need to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You could use VBA to go through and update the `.Formula` property of the cells?  Or, (*risky* option!) look up the old Excel 4.0 `EVALUATE` function, which can be run through Named Ranges

Comment: Not sure Evaluate would work as you need to return the formula string and then evaluate that within the current context. But VBA route definitely.